# pandas transform dataframe id column to a dictionary and corresponding columns to list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform my dataframe to a dictionary where the key will be an id column. I want to get all the corresponding second column values that has the respective id into a list.

Example data:

```
s1 = pd.Series(['A','A','B'],name = 's1')
s2 = pd.Series(['1','2','2'],name = 's2')

df = pd.concat([s1,s2],axis = 1)

s1 s2
A  1
A  2
B  2
```

**Output i want**

How can i get a dictionary with the mapping:

```
d = {'A':[1,2],'B':[2]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two more option

```
df.groupby('s1').s2.apply(list).to_dict()
Out[44]: {'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['2']}

s=df.groupby('s1').s2.apply(list)
dict(zip(s.index,s))
Out[48]: {'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['2']}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use pandas:

```
df.groupby("s1").s2.apply(lambda s:s.tolist()).to_dict()
```

but I think `defaultdict` is the correct method:

```
from collections import defaultdict

s1 = ['A','A','B']
s2 = ['1','2','2']

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(s1, s2):
    d[k].append(v)
```

Comment: Why do you think `defaultdict` preferable to the pandas solution or a dict comprehension in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Pandas [groupBy functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```
{k: list(s.values) for (k, s) in df.groupby('s1')['s2']}
```

returns

```
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always like to present the `defaultdict` solution

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in zip(s1, s2):
    d[k].append(v)

dict(d)

{'A': ['1', '2'], 'B': ['2']}
```